# SNMP trap message shows source and destination as unknown

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmptrapd

I am trying to send snmp traps using TLS/DTLS with net-snmp 5.7.2 package. I am unable to see the source and destination address in my trap message. It is showing 'unknown' instead of the address.
I used the below command to send the trap.

```
snmptrap -Ci -v 3 -T our_identity=snmpd -T their_identity=manager tlstcp:{destination_ip}:10162 "" UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdStart
```

The trap I received was

```
2021-01-09 19:11:30 TLSTCP: unknown [TLSTCP: unknown]:
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (37091491) 4 days, 7:01:54.91  SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdStart
```

This is my snmptrapd configuration file.

```
[snmp] localCert manager
certSecName 20 snmpd --sn joecool
authUser log -s tsm joecool
```

I have tried using '-n' flag in the snmptrapd server to use numeric address instead of attempting hostname lookups but it didn't help.
I faced no such issue while using snmp v2 or snmp v3 (usm) for sending traps.